# does not deploy keycloak from my dockerfile on render.com

Tags: docker, dockerfile, keycloak, keycloak-connect, render.com

does not deploy keycloak, everything reaches a point well, but it ends due to time or because it does not do the entire deploy.

What can be?

dockfile

```
`FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest as builder
# Enable health and metrics support
ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=false
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=false

# Configure a database vendor
ENV KC_DB=postgres

WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
# for demonstration purposes only, please make sure to use proper certificates in     production  instead
RUN keytool -genkeypair -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -dname       "CN=server" -alias server -ext "SAN:c=DNS:localhost,IP:127.0.0.1" -keystore conf/server.keystore
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance

ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://dpg-ckkudkj****:5432/toge****
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=togeton****

ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=TZkSOTMn7Il*****
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=dpg-ckkudkjj89****

ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=ad*** 
ENV KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=chang****


ENV KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE=https://keycloak-r8x0.onrender.com
ENV KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_KEY=https://keycloak-r8x0.onrender.com

EXPOSE 8443

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh" ]
CMD ["start", "--optimized"] `
```

[Se muestr que se acaba el tiempo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF0cB.png)

[Log del deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g7jL.png)

does not deploy keycloak, everything reaches a point well, but it ends due to time or because it does not do the entire deploy.

Comment: If the deployment seems to be successful but the deployment is timing out, it could be a healthcheck issue. I see you've disabled KC's healthcheck endpoint- do you have a healthcheck url registered with render that returns a valid status code?